# I added Hangfire in my Asp.net MVC application. It created it's database. Now how can I handle two databases? And deploy them on Azure?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, database, azure, hangfire

I added Hangfire in my project. Now I have two databases one for my application and one for Hangfire. I have two connection strings one for Hangfire and another is the default. Now how can I deploy my project having two databases? On Azure when I create new SQL Database it asks for one connection string. What to do now? If I create one database on Azure then how will I access another?

**Here are my connections strings**:

[image: Connection Strings]

**Here are my databases:**

[image]

**Here is my create SQL Database wizard where I have to put one connection string:**

[image]

Comment: I think Hangfire can create its own database, it just needs a connection string so you don't need to manually create any databases. You can also configure it to use your main database so that you only have 1 database.

Comment: @AlaaMasoud Yes, I did this. I mean I gave Hangfire "DefaultConnection"  database name and it added its database table in my existing database now I have one database and one connection string. But what if I want Hangfire stuff in another database? I mean is it possible?

Comment: Yes of course it is possible. You can either manually create it in the azure portal or using the azure CLI or follow Brando's answer below. I also think that Hangfire can create the database automatically if it doesnt exist so you just need to specify the connection string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But what if I want Hangfire stuff in another database? I mean is it possible?

Yes, you could store the Hangfire logs to another azure database.

As far as I know, if you use VS2017 and install the newest azure SDK.

You could create multiple sql server database when you publish.

Image like this:

[image]

In the creating sql database window, you could set the connectionstring name.

[image]

After publishing completely, it will auto set the connection string in the web app's application setting. This connection string setting will override the web config's connection string.

[image]

You just need to change the connection string name in the code as published connection string name.

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("the connection string name when you create sql database set");
```

Besides, if you still want to use local sql database, you could use Hybrid Connections. More details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-hybrid-connection-connect-on-premises-sql-server).